# variable is returning two values, how to store them in different variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

My variable is returning two values and i have to pass these values at the same time in a shell script.

`echo $var`

output :

> 23514
>   abcd

Now i have to run a shell script with 23514 and 'abcd' as arguments
`sh sample.sh --id var1 --value var2`

Comment: A variable cannot contain _two_ values. Either it is an array or (more likely here) the value contains a line break

Comment: And if it contains a line break, it would get turned into a space unless you quote the variable when echoing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
vars=($var)
sh sample.sh --id ${vars[0]} --value ${vars[1]}
```

Comment: echo ${vars[0]} is returning null and echo ${vars[1]} is returning
23514
abcd

Comment: var=$(sh new.sh | grep -E "Id|type"|grep -Eo '[0-9]+|abcd|efgh')

Comment: Have you modified `$IFS` in your script?

Comment: how can i store the multiple output of grep in different variables ??

Comment: This is the way to do it. There's something you're not showing, because it works for me.

Comment: I ran this "vara=$(echo "$var" | tr '\n' ' ')" and then "echo $vars", I got the output space separated: 23514 abcd

Is it possible now to store these vales in different variable ??

Comment: If `echo $vars` produces `23514 abcd` space separated, then the code snippet given in the answer should work as-is.

Answer (score 3):

Either use an array, as [Barmar has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18009582/793796);

or use `read` with here-string:

```
read var1 var2 <<< $var
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var1=`echo $var | awk '{print $1}'`
var2=`echo $var | awk '{print $2}'`
```